# How to manage real time update on xamarin forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

BranchId : 1000236
Users in Branch : 6

Suppose 6 users are logged in my application,and any user changes any data that are comming form web server it will automatically effects on others users mobile app immediately.so how to manage this changes on real time(when user offline,after comming to online then it will changes the users data)?
so
Firebase can help on this realtime changes?
or suggest any other technology for this real time chnages?

Now I am using Device Timer for update this data on every 10 second,but I thing this is not a good process for realtime updates.and device timer always updating the local database data.

Comment: Well what you can do is notify your device that there was a change using push notifications and then in your xamarin side right code to update data once you receive that type of notification

Comment: Firebase can help for this side? or suggest any other process?

Comment: Firebase should be more than enough you just need to add an identifier of some kind into your firebase data payload that tells you that there has been a change in the database.

Comment: Actually I am using Device Timer for update the data every 10 seconds,what do you think is it the good process?or this process can hamper my application performance?

Comment: Well Every 10 seconds might be too much if you do not handle the memory properly the android will reach OOM within 30 mins or so as per my calculation, I wouldn't recommend this solution.

Comment: You could use SignalR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some reading on SignalR.  James Montemagno wrote a blog post about it detailing how to make it happen within Xamarin, he also posted a video on YouTube.

It's not without it's challenges so tread carefully and make sure it's the right solution for you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afUbnWlJM7M

https://montemagno.com/real-time-communication-for-mobile-with-signalr/